# How do I stop playing audio when the home button is pressed?

Tags: android, audio, android-service, android-homebutton

My application always runs a background audio in services. When I click the home button, the control comes back to home screen but the audio keeps on playing.

So, how can I stop playing audio when I click the home button?

Comment: What specifically is the problem? Most audio players *want* to continue playing after the user leaves the application.

Comment: @CommonsWare I actually started to write the opposite answer (how to keep it playing), until I read the question a third time.

Answer (score 2):

If the audio is being played by a `Service`, then it won't be affected if an `Activity` is being destroyed. That is exactly the purpose of separating it into a Service.

If you want it to be dependent on your UI, then move the play to the Activity instead. It will stop when the Activity finishes. Alternatively, you can send a message to the Service in order to stop the music.

See the dev guide for more details: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html

Comment: I'm doing something similar, and I made the audio as a service, how do I stop the service when the home button is pressed?

Comment: Where in the activity

Answer (score 0):

Your activity can override onPause() and/or onWindowFocusChanged() to detect that you're no longer running or on top of the display. These are good places to stop playing audio that isn't intended to be playing if the activity isn't visible, you just have to be careful about switching to other activities within your application.

Comment: I want to play audio in background throughout my application .but when i press home button i want to stop the service .i also want that while switching between activities audio should keep playing..

Answer (score 0):

Override `onPause()` and resume it on `onResume()`.

Why you play the music on `Service`?

In that case, use `bindService()` and `unbindService()`. So the Service can respond to `onDestroy()` when `Activity` call `unbindService()`.